# Load data from local excel file to an ASP.NET MVC web app to store in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

1. When I run the web app, I want to automatically open an Excel file that's on my computer, get the data from it, and create a table with Entity Framework and C# in my database
2. Then I want to store that data retrieved from the Excel file into the table created
3. Would be repeated for each sheet or Excel file opened

I have read some other posts related to this and they all created like an upload file input box on the web app,

But I want it to be done as soon as I run the web app.

I would really appreciate suggestions/help/guidance on how to go about this without having to upload the file or click anything from the user.

Comment: Do you want to read the excel file data once when the web app run for the first time?

Comment: @Nasir Islam Sujan
My goal is to get a logic/understand how it would be done, then I would probably put like a button "Update" that when clicked by admin would run the code to read the local excel file, get the data and stores in the database

Answer (score 0):

To acheive your goal you could try below things:

Create a `Resource` folder to your current project root directory and put your excel file on that path.

```
var pathToExcelFile = Server.MapPath("~/Resource/Demo.xlsx");
```

If you want to read excel file from your Local Drive e.g. `D:` Drive:
(keep in mind this is not recommended)

```
var pathToExcelFile = @"D:\Demo.xlsx";
```

Then you have to take help of `OleDb` to read excel file data.

```
string oleConnStr = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\";", pathToExcelFile);
var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", oleConnStr);
var ds = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(ds, "ExcelTable");
DataTable dt = ds.Tables["ExcelTable"];
```

After that build your database connection and write insert logic:

```
var mssqlConnStr = "Data Source= .; DataBase= Demo; Integrated Security = true;";

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(mssqlConnStr))
{
       conn.Open();

       foreach (DataRow dataRow in dt.Rows)
       {
            var query = "INSERT INTO UserWiseSales (UserId, Sales) VALUES (@UserId, @Sales)";
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", dataRow["UserId"].ToString());
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sales", dataRow["Sales"].ToString());
            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
}
```

To run the above code as soon as your web app run, you have to put the code inside a method and call it from `Application_Start` method under `Global.asax.cs` file.

Hope this will help.